# How to get Google Sheets CTRL-D "Fill Down" to behave like Excel when single cell selected

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

If there is a value in cell A1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> while a single cell A2 is selected behaves differently in Excel and Google Sheets:

- Excel: copies cell A1 to cell A2
- Sheets: nothing

The Excel behavior is documented and demonstrated [here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/shortcut-duplicating-formulae-text-objects-excel) under "Duplicating Into a Single Cell."

Is there any way to get Google Sheets to behave like Excel when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is used?

Comment: ctrl+d seems to be working fine for me, is your only complaint that you have to highlight two cells before pressing ctrl+d?

Comment: @CodeCamper: yes. I fill down a single cell all the time and wish I could skip highlighting the cells beforehand like in Excel

Comment: You can create macros now but the shortcuts are very limited, ctrl+d is already taken for example so the answer is going to be no as of today, but if you were a little flexible there would be ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Any shortcut would be an improvement.

Comment: is all you want to copy the cell above?

Comment: @CodeCamper: Yes. I recorded a macro to bind CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-0 to do what I want based on your previous comment. A little slow/unwieldy, but it works!

Comment: great, you should post an answer to your own question clearly outlining how to do it, also you can use AutoHotKey to bind ctrl+d to ctrl+alt+shift+0 but then ctrl+d won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+D works if you select the first cell too. In excel, if you ctrl+D in one cell it understands the cell above is the original, if you select 2 or more it takes the first selected as the original. Google sheets does the same except the 1st mentioned case. You always have to select the original data cell too